# set up multiple virtual hosts on apach2 local mac

Tags: php, apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up multiple virtual hosts on my local apache2 server. My goal is to be able to go to "zf2-tutorial.localhost" in the browser for my Zend project and then go to "symfony.localhost" for my Symfony project. Right now my Zend project gets served up no matter if i go to "zf2-tutorial.localhost" or "symfony.localhost". Here's part of my http.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/myusername/Sites/Zend/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /Users/myusername/Sites/Zend/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony.localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/myusername/Sites/symfony
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    ServerAlias www.symfony.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

My "hosts" file ends with these two lines

```
127.0.0.1 zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost
127.0.0.1 symfony.localhost localhost
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Apache before version [2.3.11](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost), then you forgot to use the [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

You should also read up on the Apache Virtual Host documentation for version [2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) or [2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/).

Comment: thanks! that did it. I added that line above my two <VirtualHost *:80> tags and it worked like a charm.